# How to add activity(Appointments, Tasks) in Xamarin.Forms by using calendar control inside applicatoin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, calendar, calendarview, appointment

I am creating an application and in that there is a need to display calendar inside the particular page or block and inside the calendar there are display particular activity on the day like on 27th April it display 4th Saturday and so on depend on the run time.

I am using .Net standard 2.0 and try to make with `XamForms.Controls.Calendar` but it doesn't work for me.

I need to implement calendar with free plugin and full .Net standard support.

Can anyone look into this and suggest me what should I have to change in code or configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display the particular activity on specific day, you can use `SpecialDate` in `XamForms.Controls.Calendar` to achieve that, I set the `FontSize = 0` to make the date invisable and set `Selectable = false` to disable the select action:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Calendar calendar = new Calendar
        {
            MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
            MinDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
            MultiSelectDates = false,
            DisableAllDates = false,
            WeekdaysShow = true,
            ShowNumberOfWeek = true,

            ShowNumOfMonths = 1,
            EnableTitleMonthYearView = true,
            WeekdaysTextColor = Color.Teal,
            StartDay = DayOfWeek.Monday,
            SelectedTextColor = Color.Fuchsia,
            SpecialDates = new List<SpecialDate>{
                new SpecialDate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2))
                {
                    BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                    TextColor = Color.White,

                    Selectable = false,
                    FontSize = 0,

                    BackgroundPattern = new BackgroundPattern(1)
                    {
                        Pattern = new List<Pattern>
                        {
                            new Pattern{ WidthPercent = 1f, HightPercent = 1f, Color = Color.White,Text = "4th Saturday", TextColor=Color.DarkBlue, TextSize=8, TextAlign=TextAlign.Middle}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Content = new ScrollView
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(5, Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ? 25 : 5, 5, 5),
                Children = {
                        calendar//,c2
                    }
            }
        };        

    }
```

Here is the result:

[image: calendarview]

If you want to show all the Saturday, you should calculate the date yourself and pass the date as a parameter in `DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)`.

Comment: Hi @Jack, Thanks for reply. Firstly I want to tell that when I am using `.Net Standard 2.0` and when I try to install nuget that you pass it to me than it installed proper but shows warning in nuget. Can you please check that what should missing here?

Comment: @DeepSoni I don't know what is missing here. The warning let users know that the assets may not be 100% compatible. However, when I installed it and it works well on my side. And the only dependency on its website is Xamarin.Forms (>= 2.3.4.231). You can check if there is any problem when using.

Comment: Hi @Jack Thanks for reply. I am using Xamarin.Forms 3.5 and my activity is depends on the api call when I try to click on button particular user's all activity like task, appointments, calls are display in calendar.

Comment: @DeepSoni What's your question? When you get response from api, you can set `calendar.SpecialDates` to show the particular user's all activity like task, appointments, calls in calendar.

Comment: Thanks for help. It really helps me a lot.